# Google API to recover data

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

in google drive, there's a tab named "backups" that contains data from old android phones I have.
These backups are not downloadable.

Is there a way to download these backup files? is there a way to get the information inside the backup files?  ( API requests )

I know that for the Whatsapp backup-file there is a different API (because it's not downloadable like the others).

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of accessing the backup folder in Drive API. But, if you're referring to a special folder called App Folder which is only accessible by your application, then you can. Check the [Get authorization to use the App Folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder).